# JBehave @BeforeStory webdriver usage

Tags: selenium-webdriver, jbehave

I'm using the JBehave tutorial (Spring) https://github.com/jbehave/jbehave-tutorial with just 1 change, replacing `PerStoryWebDriverSteps` to `PerStoriesWebDriverSteps`.

When I try to use webDriver inside `@BeforeStory` I have this error message:

```
org.jbehave.web.selenium.DelegatingWebDriverProvider$DelegateWebDriverNotFound: WebDriver has not been found for this thread.
```

With this step:

```
public class LifecycleSteps {

    private final WebDriverProvider webDriverProvider;

    public LifecycleSteps(WebDriverProvider webDriverProvider) {
        this.webDriverProvider = webDriverProvider;
    }

    @BeforeStory
    public void test() {
        webDriverProvider.get();
    }
...
}
```

I just want to know if it's a bug, a misconfiguration or not possible to use webDriver in `@BeforeStory`?

In past I used Behat/Mink (PHP BDD) and It was not possible to use webDriver inside `@BeforeStory` because webDriver was not load. But in Jbehave you can select the webDriver init by using `PerXXXXWebDriverSteps`. And I thought it was possible to use webDriver in `@BeforeStory` if webDriver is init in `@BeforeStories` (using `PerStoriesWebDriverSteps`)

Comment: Did you tried using webDriverProvider.initialize() before the first webDriverProvider.get()? I had a similar issue with @BeforeStories and this solved.

Comment: It could work but it will load a new webdriver object that will not shared with the webdriver object used after for stories. Btw I have changed my way to do and I'm now in PerScenario lifecycle